# Can this function be a density function of a continuous random variable X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions

F(x) = 0, if x < 1
F(x) = 1, if 1<=x<=2
F(x) = 0, if x>2

I think it could be, as long as the integral is 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you argued correctly.  I would rather call it $f(x)$.  That way, $F(x)$ can be used for the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: thanks Andre! Do you also know that why Q (rational number field) does not have a finite subfield? How to prove it?

Comment: You are welcome. Any subfield contains the unit element $1$. But then since it is closed under addition, it contains all positive integers. There are infinitely many already. You can o on to prove (easily) that the only subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks Andre. Btw, did you find that I have a fancy name?

Comment: Yes, I noticed, a very famous name. Also fancy in the social sense, but that is of no interest.

Comment: The word 'continuous' in your title is redundant. If a random variable has a PDF then it is by definition 'absolutely continuous'. That is even stronger than continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is the probability density function of a [random variable distributed uniformly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) on the interval $[1,2]$.

As well as having an integral across the real numbers of $1$, a probability density function also needs to be non-negative.  Your function has this property.